# Swift PythonKit with error for no module found

Tags: python, swift, swift-pythonkit

I'm trying to run some python code from Xcode but wasn't sure why it can't find the module. All the tutorial I found only shows importing the simple .py file that contains function only no import on the top. I'm using python3. TIA

```
import SwiftUI
import PythonKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .onAppear() {
            runPython()
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func runPython() {
        let sys = Python.import("sys")
        sys.path.append(Config.Path.basePath)
        let test = Python.import("example")
        let response = test.hello()
        print(response)
    }
}
```

example.py

```
import pandas

def hello():
    return "Hello Python"
```

Error:

> PythonKit/Python.swift:706: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Python exception: No module named 'pandas'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out that I had pandas install in the wrong Python version.

```
$ python3.11 -m pip install pandas
```

fixed it.